# How to make tab bar icon image small?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I want to make the tab tab bar icon images look little small.I have used 30*30 size images and also 60*60 images.but it still does not work for me.Please guide me how can i get the correct solution.

following is my code

```
//set the custom images for selected & unselected image for tab bar
    UITabBarItem *homeTab = [self.exposeTabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImage *home_unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
    UIImage *home_selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
    [homeTab setImage: [home_unselectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [homeTab setSelectedImage: home_selectedImage];

    UITabBarItem *bookmarkTab = [self.exposeTabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UIImage *bookmark_unselectedImage_ = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark.png"];
    UIImage *bookmark_selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark.png"];
    [bookmarkTab setImage: [bookmark_unselectedImage_ imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [bookmarkTab setSelectedImage: bookmark_selectedImage];

    UITabBarItem *postTab = [self.exposeTabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    UIImage *post_unselectedImage_ = [UIImage imageNamed:@"create-post.png"];
    UIImage *post_selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"create-post_white.png"];
    [postTab setImage: [post_unselectedImage_ imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [postTab setSelectedImage: post_selectedImage];

    UITabBarItem *notificationTab = [self.exposeTabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
    UIImage *notification_unselectedImage_ = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notifications.png"];
    UIImage *notification_selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notifications_white.png"];
    [notificationTab setImage: [notification_unselectedImage_ imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [notificationTab setSelectedImage: notification_selectedImage];

    UITabBarItem *profileTab = [self.exposeTabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];
    UIImage *profile_unselectedImage_ = [UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"];
    UIImage *profile_selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"more_white.png"];
    [profileTab setImage: [profile_unselectedImage_ imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [profileTab setSelectedImage: profile_selectedImage];

    self.exposeTabBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.exposeTabBar.selectedImageTintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];


    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor] }
                                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }
                                             forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Are you using `Assets.xcassets`??

Comment: Yes.But i don't know why it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Use following like wise code for setting the image of the UITabBar.

```
UITabBarItem *i0 = [self.tabBar.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
[i0 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home"]];
```

It's working on my case.

Comment: how do i add selected or unselect image then.Please tell.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `imageInsets` and play with values until it suits your needs.

```
self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 6, 6, 6);
```